# MS Word is an MDI or SDI

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-7, ms-word

I have a confusion that MSWord is a MDI or SDI application. Looking at the Application, I do believe that it is a SDI application but there are people who strongly "believe" that its an example of MDI. After using the Taskmanager in windows, the Applications tab list all all the instances of the Documents currently opened. However there is only one process in the **Processes** tab.

Since all the documents have same process, it make me feel its an MDI. But at the same time, the **Applications** tab lists all the documents opened make methink its an SDI. What do you people think about this? Please give your valuable and detailed answers.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: MDI/SDI has pretty much nothing at all to do with processes. It has to do with how multiple windows are displayed. Either way, this does not appear to be a programming question at all, so I voted to migrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across some more info regarding this from [Chris Ryan](http://tinyurl.com/3jfwy89)  which I am sharing here:

---

It depends on what you mean by MDI.

MS-Word does have multiple documents and an interface but it does not fit the classic definition of an MDI application because it does not use an MDICLIENT window class to manage the child frames.

For an example of an MDICLIENT, see: 
ftp://ftp.charlespetzold.com/ProgWin5/Chap19/MDIDemo/MDIDemo.c . 
ftp://ftp.charlespetzold.com/ProgWin5/Chap19/MDIDemo/Release/MDIDemo.exe

Even the older versions of Word and Excel that had the child windows inside the main frame, were technically not MDI. They looked like it but they did not use MDICLIENT. MS used a proprietary windowing library called Software Dialog Manager. SDM was used so a common application code base could be used on multiple platforms: Windows, OS/2, & Mac. All they had to do was recompile for that platform and link a platform specific SDM library.

This link talks a little about SDM but does not mention MDICLIENT 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317997(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: MDI has nothing to do with how the application is written, and older MS word is definitely MDI. MDICLIENT is just a way to implement MDI... not the only way.

Answer (score 7):

If you uncheck `Show all documents in the taskbar` in Options, Word is a classical MDI application (even Word 2010).

If you leave it checked, it's an SDI application with multiple root windows.

Comment: If I do **Show all documents in taskbar** all the documents will be seperate otherwise they will be part of the same parent window. I agree.
But the confusion is 
** (1) ** that same documents whenopened can be switched to MDI from SDI and vice-vera
** (2) ** If all the documents have same PID, how is it SDI? I believe fro SDI, each window is a process.

Comment: SDI does not require each window to be its own process.

Comment: @RaymondChen, please share your thoughts for info fiven by Chris

Comment: First you need to define what MDI/SDI mean before you can discuss whether Word is one. Ryan's definition appears to be "uses the MDICLIENT window class", which is a very narrow definition.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, it is an MDI application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263481(v=vs.60).aspx

Depending on your settings and version, it could be MDI or SDI. It is MDI in older versions and if you use the "Show all documents in taskbar" option; otherwise, it is SDI.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I didn't realize this part myself, until I tested:

> After using the Taskmanager in windows, the Applications tab list all all the instances of the Documents currently opened. However there is only one process in the Processes tab.

Thank you and +1 on the post. On exploring further, I found something that might shed light further. I am using 2007, but I guess it would apply for 2010 as well. I clicked on the Control Menu (the small menu that pops up when you click on the Icon on the top left corner - used to be called Control Menu, before Microsoft decided to redraw its interface). You would find a "Word Options" button. Click on it, in the dialog that pops up after that, go to "Advanced" tab. Scroll down to the "Display" section. Locate the "Show all windows in the Taskbar" check box, I guess it will be checked. Uncheck it. You would see that there are no multiple windows (corresponding to each document) anymore. Also, in Task Manager, you will see only one instance even in the Applications Tab.

With this, I strongly believe Word is still an MDI. Oh by the way, if you want to see every document opened after you change these "Advanced" options, you might want to go to View menu and and chose "View side by side" option.

Comment: yes that makes me too think of MDI app. However, then what do they meas "turning to SDI" by unchecking check box "Show all..."